# hide a specfic row in DataGrid asp.net using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

This seems pretty easy to anyone but i cannot search on how to hide a speficic row in DataGrid(Not GridView) in asp.net using vb. When i was searching, i only saw on how to hide a column using   DataGrid1.Columns(0).Visible = False. I tried hiding it using ItemDataBound event but it hides the whole column along with its headercolumntext.

My aim is to search data with using a textbox where Date = textboxdate.text. This is easy to do in sql but i cannot revise the query because it is in a stored procedure.

This is my current code:

```
 If txtAdmDate.Text <> "" Then

        If Not String.Equals(txtAdmDate.Text, e.Item.Cells(0).Text) Then
            e.Item.Cells(0).Visible = False
        End If

    End If
```

I want to make something like this.

```
    Private Sub DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.ItemDataBound
    If txtAdmDate.Text <> "" Then
        If DataGrid1.Row(0).text <> txtAdmDate.Text Then
            DataGrid1.Row(0).Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

ASPX page:

```
Search By Date:
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdmDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Refresh / Search" />
<br />
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Admission Date" HeaderText="Admission Date"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Hospital #" HeaderText="Hosp. #"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Admission #" HeaderText="Reg. #"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Patient Name" HeaderText="Patient Name" Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:ButtonColumn DataTextField="Patient Name"  HeaderText="Patient Name" CommandName="Select"></asp:ButtonColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Discharged Date" HeaderText="Discharged Date"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Billing Date" HeaderText="Billing Date"></asp:BoundColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this Lines

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" 
OnItemDataBound="DataGrid1_ItemDataBound"
 CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" 
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

IN Code Behind

```
Protected Sub DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridItemEventArgs)
     Dim Row As DataGridItem
    Row = DataGrid1.Item

    ' Dim txbox As TextBox
    ' txbox = CType(Row.FindControl("txtbox"), TextBox)
    ' this for template fields Only

    'if you used BoundFields you can access like this

 If Not String.Equals(txtAdmDate.Text, Row.Cells(0).Text) Then
            Row.Visible = False
        End If


    End Sub 'Item_Bound 

' this will give you selected row 
' from this you can find controls on that row like text boxes,labels
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagriditemeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. The highlighted line is If Not String.Equals(txtAdmDate.Text, Row.Cells(0).Text) Then

Comment: does the line "Row = GridView1.SelectedItem" makes the error? because i am not selecting any item.

Comment: @Dale where is your txtAdmDate?? if it is Outside DataGrid then you can check my updated code

Comment: it is outside the DataGrid and it is an asptextbox

Comment: i changed the code into                                           If Not String.Equals(txtAdmDate.Text, e.Item.Cells(0).Text) Then
      e.Item.Cells(0).Visible = False
End If                                                                 and its working, but it just hides the first column, no the whole row.

Comment: try this now i updated `Dim Row As DataGridItem
    Row = DataGrid1.Item` will give you Current Row for datagrid and `e.Item.Cells(0).Visible= False ` will hides only first cell for that grid

Comment: 'Item' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid'